# android determine if device is in right to left language/layout

Tags: android, right-to-left

Is there a way to determine if the device is in a right to left language (something like Arabic) as opposed to something that's left to right (English)?

Something compatible with older API levels (down to 10) is necessary

**SOLUTION**

i ended up using the xml method in the accepted answer. Farther down the line, i also added the code indicated here for instances where I didn't have access to getResources()

[Identifying RTL language in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996183/identifying-rtl-language-in-android/23203698#23203698)

**more info**

This question still gets a lot of traffic; something else I wanted to point out: When I originally asked this I think it was partially to help address showing different pointing chevrons in RTL vs LTR -- another slick way of accomplishing this is by placing drawable resources in the standard and `ldrtl` directories -- means no code required to determine which one to show!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You could create a **values-ldrtl** folder with a xml file called isrighttoleft.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="is_right_to_left">true</bool>
</resources>
```

and in your **values** folder the same file with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="is_right_to_left">false</bool>
</resources>
```

And finally in Code:

```
boolean isRightToLeft = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_right_to_left);
```

The values-ldrtl will only be used on a device where the specific settings (e. g. Language) are right-to-left-read languages.

Comment: Thanks. I normally use this "technique" to determine wether the app is running on a tablet device or not ;)

Comment: I ended up using this over my solution because the above works all the time, my solution doesnt work inside onCreateView

Comment: Glad I could help you out ;)

Comment: Might want to add a "?>" to end of first line on those xml files, just for correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks. Just added them... ;)

Comment: You don't need extra resources for this. Check out my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47119946/878126

Comment: I added this line in my strings resource files. no need to create special file for it

Comment: The only working answer

Comment: This will crash on old android devices.

Answer (score 45):

I think this is a better way:

```
val isLeftToRight = TextUtilsCompat.getLayoutDirectionFromLocale(Locale.getDefault()) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR
```

Docs:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/text/TextUtilsCompat.html#getLayoutDirectionFromLocale(java.util.Locale)

Or, if you have minAPI 17 or above, you can just use this:

```
val isLeftToRight=TextUtils.getLayoutDirectionFromLocale(Locale.getDefault())==View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR
```

Docs:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#getLayoutDirectionFromLocale(java.util.Locale)

Comment: I just tested this in Android 10 with the device language set to Arabic, which my app is not translated into, and `Locale.getDefault()` returned `en_US` with `LTR` layout direction. Maybe this method gets the _app_'s locale's layout direction instead of the device's?

Comment: @Sam In that case it's correct. If the app is in English, you want to treat it as LTR without respect to device's language.

Comment: @Sam `Locale.getDefault()` is supposed to return the current OS locale. Maybe you didn't set it right, or you didn't call the function again with the updated result of `Locale.getDefault()`. The code works with what it has. If it says it's English, it's LTR.

Answer (score 28):

Gr, a little bit longer googling and I would have found it before posting:

```
if (ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(getView()) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR) {
    // ...
}
else {
    // ...
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#getLayoutDirection(android.view.View)

Comment: You don't need a view to get it. Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47119946/878126

Answer (score 10):

Kotlin Code for detect app layout direction :

```
 val config = resources.configuration
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        if (config.layoutDirection == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR) {
           // showAlertMsg("LTR")
        } else {
           // showAlertMsg( "RTL")
        }
    }
    else {
        //TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < JELLY_BEAN_MR1")
           }
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using [Core KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#core)

you could use:

```
if (Locale.getDefault().layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.RTL)
```

Comment: if api 19 is fine

Answer (score 5):

If this is still getting considerable traffic, people should also consider Configuration.getLayoutDirection(), for API 17+. It will return either LayoutDirection.LTR or LayoutDirection.RTL. I imagine ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(android.view.View) returns the direction that was actually used to layout a particular view. If you're doing something weird, such as trying to determine which person should be on which side of a chat screen (like me), this might be of use.

Comment: There is a way for it to work on all API versions, without a view, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47119946/878126

Comment: I think it's good to use ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(android.view.View) because it's common to hardcode direction of some views to not rotate in RTL languages or vice versa.

Comment: The poster asked the following: "Is there a way to determine if the device is in a right to left language". My answer is that there is a method in Configuration that does exactly this. These methods that have been suggested in View and ViewCompat, check only for a specific View, not the device.

Answer (score 2):

That's so easy. Just use: **isRtll()**

```
override fun isRtl(): Boolean {
    return super.isRtl()
}
```

Have a fun!

Answer (score 1):

If your `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is bigger than `JELLY_BEAN (16)` you can use this:

```
val locale = Locale.getDefault() 
val isLtr = TextUtils.getLayoutDirectionFromLocale(locale) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,use the Bidi.getBaseLevel() function, it will return 0 for left-to-right and 1 for right to left.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Bidi.html#getBaseLevel()

Comment: I would have to have an instance of Bidi correct? In any case, I found a solution that seems to work. thanks though!

Comment: Yes, you have to istantiate one.

Comment: Please post the solution you found, for future reference. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to create a new instance of anything. You can use this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47119946/878126