# Messed up Arabic String in Android

Tags: android, arabic

I have a String where i have to show  to  in a layout.
In english it is showing fine but in arabic it is messed up :-

in English :-
01-Oct-2014 to 10-Nov-2014

in Arabic :-
01-Oct-2014 إلى 01-Nov-2014

**The arabic rendering is like above. How can we move the to in arabic in middle ?**

in Code :-

```
    holder.mPeriodTv.setText(presenter.getViewContext().getString(R.string.bill_period, startDate, endDate));
```

in arabic strings :-

```
    <string name="bill_period"><xliff:g id="from">%s</xliff:g> إلى <xliff:g id="todate">%s</xliff:g></string>
```

in english strings :-

```
<string name="bill_period"><xliff:g id="from">%s</xliff:g> to <xliff:g id="todate">%s</xliff:g></string>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964488/how-to-make-the-text-direction-from-right-to-left

Answer (score 0):

- `String str = "‏‏‏‏\u200f" + str` ‏‏‏‏\u200f means the text is RTL
- "‏‏‏‏`\u200f`Your text is right to left"
- https://android.jlelse.eu/rtl-support-on-android-here-is-all-you-need-know-e13f2df512e2
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30415888/4650581
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23203698/4650581
- [android determine if device is in right to left language/layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26549354/4650581)