# Text with number is disorder in RTL mode (Android)

Tags: java, android, right-to-left

Text like "20 minutes before" will be "minutes before 20" in RTL mode.

I feel like the system takes number as Arabic word, thus force 20 to the very right of the text.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Mytext"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="end|right|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingStart="4dp"
    android:text="5 minutes before"
    android:textDirection="locale"/>
```

Original string "20 minutes before" is expected.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302221/android-setting-with-textview-for-hebrew-text/6302325#6302325). See if it helps

Comment: You can find solution in below link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26550588/10711216

Answer (score 2):

if you delete "android:textDirection="locale"", then you can see what you want. i don't know which direction you want the "5 minutes before" showing. if left in RTL and LTL mode, you can set " android:gravity="start|center_vertical"", else if right "android:gravity="end|center_vertical"

Comment: Actually, it's probably better to explicitly mark this text field with `android:textDirection="ltr"`, at least as long as the text is not translated to Arabic.

Answer (score 1):

use this,

```
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Mytext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:text="20 minutes before"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This will cause bugs when the systems language is RTL language like Arabic, etc by  forcing text direction to LTR.

Comment: Remove LTR , it will work fine for both English and Arabic.I edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/Mytext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:text="5 minutes before"/>
```

Output for LTR

> 5 minutes before

Output for RTL

> before minutes 5

Comment: Sorry for making it unclear, i'd like it to be '5 minutes before' even in RTL, and I found out the root reason for this disorder is that when System reads a string like "5 minutes before", it will consider its direction based on first character, in this case, is 5. 5 is either English and Arabic, the system will take it as Arabic somehow and caused this bug. To avoid this, simply add UniCode U+2068 to skip leading numbers, everything is gonna be fine. http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Directional_Formatting_Characters

Answer (score 0):

According to:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#supportsrtl

> android:supportsRtl
>
> Declares whether your application is willing to support right-to-left
>   (RTL) layouts.  If set to true and targetSdkVersion is set to 17 or
>   higher, various RTL APIs will be activated and used by the system so
>   your app can display RTL layouts. If set to false or if
>   targetSdkVersion is set to 16 or lower, the RTL APIs will be ignored
>   or will have no effect and your app will behave the same regardless of
>   the layout direction associated to the user's Locale choice (your
>   layouts will always be left-to-right).

so, if this is what you want to achieve than simply set `android:supportsRtl = false` in Manifest.