# How to check if the device uses the right-to-left direction using Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

On Android we can use [android determine if device is in right to left language/layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549354/android-determine-if-device-is-in-right-to-left-language-layout).

But does Jetpack Compose provide any API to check the layout direction? Without interacting with the resources or other Android APIs.

Answer (score 11):

We can use [LocalLayoutDirection](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary#LocalLayoutDirection())

```
Box(
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    if (LocalLayoutDirection.current == LayoutDirection.Rtl) {
        Text("RTL")
    } else {
        Text("LTR")
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds about right.