# fill my button from right to left when I change my language to persian

Tags: java, android

In my project , I want to play the sound and user must guess the sound.
every thing works well.
I have grid that show some letters and user must selected correct letters to make the right word.
when user selected letters my button fill from left  to right
my language is persian and filling my button must be from right to left.
here is my code but don't know where I do this change.

```
    public class TheGame extends Activity {
        // Variables
              //    InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private Button[] word_btn;
      private String lvl = "0";
       private String coins = "0";
       private String[] chars = { "الف", "ب", "پ", "ت", "ث", "ج", "چ", "ح", "خ",
        "د", "ذ", "ر", "ز", "ژ", "س", "ش", "ص", "ض", "ط", "ظ", "ع", "غ",
        "ف", "ق", "ک", "گ" ,"ل","م","ن","و","ه","ی"};
private String[] word_array;
private String theWord = "999";
private String resultWord = "";
public Button[] randBtn;


SoundPool soundPool;
Context mContext;
String SoundFile,Ribbon;
TextView txt_ribon;

Button btn_first,btn_bomb,btn_skip,btn_back,btn_ask;
boolean loaded = false,isLast=false;
private int soundID,Count=0;
StringBuilder sb;
public TheGame() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) >= 9) {
        try {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);
    mContext=TheGame.this;
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()).append(File.separator).append(getString(R.string.app_name));

    txt_ribon=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_ribon);
    btn_first=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    btn_bomb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btn_skip=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn_back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn_ask=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rippleanimset);
    animation.setFillAfter(false);
    animation.setRepeatCount(0x186a0);
    button.startAnimation(animation);




    // 12 orange buttons where appear letters of the word, and other letters
    randBtn = new Button[] { (Button) findViewById(R.id.char1),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char2),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char3),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char4),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char5),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char6),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char7),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char8),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char9),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char10),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char11),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char12) };
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    lvl = readData().split("\\|")[0];
    coins = readData().split("\\|")[1];
    if (Integer.parseInt(coins) < 0) {
        coins = "0";
    }
    parseXML(Integer.parseInt(lvl)-1);
    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    if(!isLast)
    {

        int sound_id = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(SoundFile, "raw",
                mContext.getPackageName());
        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                loaded = true;
            }
        });
        soundID = soundPool.load(this, sound_id, 1);

        txt_ribon.setText(Ribbon);
        word_array = getWord(theWord);
        createWord(word_array.length);
        randomChars();
        TextView lvl_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        lvl_txt.setText(" " + lvl + " ");
        TextView coins_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        coins_txt.setText(coins);
    }
    else
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.reset_msg_1));
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.reset_msg_2));
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                TheGame.this.finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.reset_title),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                writeData(getString(R.string.point_give));
                dialog.dismiss();
                TheGame.this.finish();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.show();
    }


    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button7)).setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view)
        {

            Count+=1;
            if (Count %2==1) {
                if(loaded)
                {
                    soundPool.play(soundID, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F);

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wait Sound is Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
            if (Count % 2==0) {
                soundPool.stop(soundID);
                soundPool.play(soundID, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F);
            }

        }
    });


    btn_first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        if (Integer.parseInt(coins) >= Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.how_much_for_first_letter))) {
                            btn_first.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            coins = "" + (Integer.parseInt(coins) - Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.how_much_for_first_letter)));
                            TextView coins_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                            coins_txt.setText(coins);
                            writeData("" + (Integer.parseInt(lvl)) + "|"
                                    + (Integer.parseInt(coins)));
                            word_btn[0].setText(word_array[0].toUpperCase());
                            word_btn[0].setOnClickListener(null);
                            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                                if (randBtn[i].getText().equals(
                                        word_array[0].toUpperCase())) {
                                    randBtn[i]
                                            .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    i = 12;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };

            // Check if sufficient coins
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    TheGame.this);
            builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.first_letter_msg_3)).setIcon(
                    R.drawable.help);
            if (Integer.parseInt(coins) >= Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.how_much_for_first_letter))) {
                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.first_letter_msg_1));
                builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no), dialogClickListener)
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), dialogClickListener)
                .show();
            } else {
                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.first_letter_msg_2));
                builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.ok), dialogClickListener)
                .show();
            }

        }
    });

    btn_bomb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        if (Integer.parseInt(coins) >= Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.how_much_for_bomb))) {
                            btn_bomb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            coins = "" + (Integer.parseInt(coins) - Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.how_much_for_bomb)));
                            TextView coins_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                            coins_txt.setText(coins);
                            writeData("" + (Integer.parseInt(lvl)) + "|"
                                    + (Integer.parseInt(coins)));
                            remove3Chars();
                        }
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };

            // Check if sufficient coins
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    TheGame.this);
            builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.bomb_msg_3)).setIcon(R.drawable.help);
            if (Integer.parseInt(coins) >= Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.how_much_for_bomb))) {
                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.bomb_msg_1));
                builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no), dialogClickListener)
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), dialogClickListener)
                .show();
            } else {
                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.bomb_msg_2));
                builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.ok), dialogClickListener)
                .show();
            }
        }
    });

    btn_skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        if (Integer.parseInt(coins) >= Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.how_much_for_skip))) {
                            btn_skip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            coins = "" + (Integer.parseInt(coins) - Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.how_much_for_skip)));
                            TextView coins_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                            coins_txt.setText(coins);
                            writeData("" + (Integer.parseInt(lvl) + 1) + "|"
                                    + (Integer.parseInt(coins)));
                            finish();
                            startActivity(getIntent());
                        }
                        break;
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };

            // Check if sufficient coins
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    TheGame.this);
            builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.skip_msg_3)).setIcon(R.drawable.help);
            if (Integer.parseInt(coins) >= Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.how_much_for_skip))) {
                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.skip_msg_1));
                builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no), dialogClickListener)
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), dialogClickListener)
                .show();
            } else {
                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.skip_msg_2));
                builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.ok), dialogClickListener)
                .show();
            }
        }
    });




    btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    btn_ask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String path=SaveBackground();
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/jpeg");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(path));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    soundPool.release();
}

// Function that generate black squares, depending on the number of letters
// in the word
private void createWord(int length) {
    LinearLayout world_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.world_layout);
    LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, length);

    word_btn = new Button[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        word_btn[i] = new Button(getApplicationContext());

        word_btn[i].setText("");
        word_btn[i].setId(i);
        word_btn[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        word_btn[i].setTextSize(24);
        word_btn[i].setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        word_btn[i].setLayoutParams(param);
        word_btn[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.matchbox);
        world_layout.addView(word_btn[i]);
        word_btn[i].setOnClickListener(charOnClick(word_btn[i]));
    }
}

// Function that generate random letters + word's leter on orange buttons
private void randomChars() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        randBtn[i].setOnClickListener(randCharClick(randBtn[i]));
        Random r = new Random();
        int i1 = r.nextInt(25 - 0) + 0;
        randBtn[i].setText(chars[i1]);
    }

    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(list);

    for (int x = 0; x < word_array.length; x++) {
        int value = list.remove(0);
        randBtn[value].setText(word_array[x]);
    }
}

// Fuction that clear wrong letter from black squares
private OnClickListener charOnClick(final Button button) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                if (randBtn[i].getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE
                        && randBtn[i].getText() == button.getText())
                    randBtn[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            button.setText("");

        }
    };
}

// Function for orange buttons
private OnClickListener randCharClick(final Button btn) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            for (int i = 0; i < word_array.length; i++) {
                if (word_btn[i].getText() == "") {
                    word_btn[i].setText(btn.getText());
                    i = word_array.length;
                }
            }
            createResult();
        }
    };
}

// Function that check if the word is correct and showing correct/wrong
// dialog
private void createResult() {
    resultWord = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < word_array.length; i++) {
        if (word_btn[i].getText() != "") {
            resultWord +=word_btn[i].getText();
        }
    }

    if (resultWord.length() == word_array.length) {
        if (resultWord.equalsIgnoreCase(theWord)) {
            showMyDialog(1, null);
        } else {
            showMyDialog(2, null);
        }
    }
}

// Function that transform the word to array
private String[] getWord(String str) {
    String[] chars = str.split("");
    List<String> selected_chars = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        selected_chars.add(chars[i]);
    }
    selected_chars.remove(0);
    return selected_chars.toArray(new String[selected_chars.size()]);
}

// //Function that showing dialogs: correct, wrong or zooming image
private void showMyDialog(final int type, String bmp) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(TheGame.this, R.style.dialogStyle);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    dialog.getWindow().getDecorView()
    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dialog_bg);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    String points = ""
            + ((new Random().nextInt(10 - 3) + 3) + word_array.length);
    SmartImageView image = (SmartImageView) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.imageDialog);
    Button dialogBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogBtn);
    TextView score = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.points);

    if (type == 1) {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.corect);
        dialogBtn.setText(" Continue "); // Next level button
        score.setText("+" + points);
        writeData("" + (Integer.parseInt(lvl) + 1) + "|"
                + (Integer.parseInt(coins) + Integer.parseInt(points)));
    } else if (type == 2) {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.gresit);
        dialogBtn.setText("  Try Again  "); // Try again button, restart
        // current level
        score.setText("-5");
        if (Integer.parseInt(coins) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(coins) <= 5) {
            writeData("" + (Integer.parseInt(lvl)) + "|"
                    + (Integer.parseInt("0")));
        } else {
            writeData("" + (Integer.parseInt(lvl)) + "|"
                    + (Integer.parseInt(coins) - 5));
        }
    } else {
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        score.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        dialogBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ImageView coinicon = (ImageView) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.dialogIcon);
        coinicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        image.setImageUrl(bmp);
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    dialog.show();

    dialogBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (type > 0) {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
//      // Button that open "Share on Facebook" dialog
//      fb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//              getBitmapFromView().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
//                      stream);
//              byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
////                Intent i = new Intent(TheGame.this, LoginFragment.class);
////                i.putExtra("image", byteArray);
////                i.putExtra("lvl", lvl);
////                startActivity(i);
//              dialog.dismiss();
//          }
//      });


// Function that save all user data. Current level, coins
private void writeData(String dataStr) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                openFileOutput("thewords.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(dataStr);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

// Function that read user data
private String readData() {
    String ret = "";
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("thewords.dat");
        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return ret;
}



// Function that hide 3 orange buttons (letters)
public void remove3Chars() {
    Button[] removeBtn = { (Button) findViewById(R.id.char1),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char2),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char3),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char4),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char5),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char6),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char7),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char8),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char9),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char10),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char11),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char12) };
    int x = 0;
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    while (x != 3) {
        int value = list.remove(0);
        if (!Arrays.asList(word_array).contains(
                removeBtn[value].getText().toString().toUpperCase())) {
            removeBtn[value].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            x += 1;

        }
    }
}

private void parseXML(int i) {
    AssetManager assetManager = getBaseContext().getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream is = assetManager.open("LevelData.xml");
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        LevelSAXParserHandler myXMLHandler = new LevelSAXParserHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        InputSource inStream = new InputSource(is);
        xr.parse(inStream);

        ArrayList<Level> cartList = myXMLHandler.getCartList();
        if(i>=cartList.size())
        {   
            isLast=true;
        }
        else
        {
            Level level=cartList.get(i); 
            theWord=level.getAnswer();
            SoundFile=level.getMusicId();
            Ribbon=level.getRibbon();

        }
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}

public String SaveBackground()
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    RelativeLayout panelResult = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
    panelResult.invalidate();
    panelResult.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    panelResult.buildDrawingCache();
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int i = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int j = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(panelResult.getDrawingCache()), j, i, true);
    panelResult.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    String s = null;
    File file;
    boolean flag;
    file = new File(sb.toString());
    flag = file.isDirectory();
    s = null;
    if (flag)
    {
    }
    file.mkdir();
    FileOutputStream fileoutputstream1 = null;
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf("guess"))).append("_sound_").append(System.currentTimeMillis()).append(".png").toString();
    try {
        fileoutputstream1 = new FileOutputStream(new File(file, s));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FileOutputStream fileoutputstream = fileoutputstream1;

    StringBuilder stringbuilder1;
    bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileoutputstream);
    stringbuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
    stringbuilder1.append(sb.toString()).append(File.separator).append(s);

    try {
        fileoutputstream.flush();
        fileoutputstream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ""+stringbuilder1;

}
```

here I CREATE place to fill by selected letter by user:

```
    private void createWord(int length) {
    LinearLayout world_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.world_layout);
    LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, length);

    word_btn = new Button[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        word_btn[i] = new Button(getApplicationContext());

        word_btn[i].setText("");
        word_btn[i].setId(i);
        word_btn[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        word_btn[i].setTextSize(24);
        word_btn[i].setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        word_btn[i].setLayoutParams(param);
        word_btn[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.matchbox);
        world_layout.addView(word_btn[i]);
        word_btn[i].setOnClickListener(charOnClick(word_btn[i]));
    }
}
```

and here i check the letters to fill:

```
    private void createResult() {
    resultWord = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < word_array.length; i++) {
        if (word_btn[i].getText() != "") {
            resultWord +=word_btn[i].getText();
        }
    }

    if (resultWord.length() == word_array.length) {
        if (resultWord.equalsIgnoreCase(theWord)) {
            showMyDialog(1, null);
        } else {
            showMyDialog(2, null);
        }
    }
}
```

now it works but my button fill from left to right 
I want to fill right to left

Comment: This is far too much code. I'd recommend you edit this down significantly and repost the question, but I'm pretty confident if you reduced the lines of code you'd be able to figure this out.

Comment: ... what about simply switching the text direction to **RTL**?

Comment: @Rotwang it is not text , my letter is in array then fill in button

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider but it is clear , this my whole code to make better clear for readers

Comment: It's probably not the right solution to this problem but keep in mind, too, that Android does allow you to have language-specific resources (so you could have special versions of your layouts for particular languages).

Comment: @EJoshuaS yes it's not the right solution

Comment: @nsr yes, I did suspect that that's not exactly what you were looking to do (which is why I put it in the comments instead of an answer), just thought I'd point that out for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:supportsRtl="true"` in `<application>` in your AndroidManifest.xml, and then `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` in your root layout.

Comment: no it is not right way. i must chane the way filling to my buttons

Comment: Please explain more. I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: if I understand correctly he needs to iterate from length - 1 to 0 in the for loop that populates the buttons rather than just using RTL layouts

Comment: So doesn't Rtl and right gravity make it populate from the right?

Answer (score 0):

Using a check if the language is right to left from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23203698/3570019), I would structure your code like this:

```
private static boolean isRTL() {
    final int directionality = Character.getDirectionality(Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName().charAt(0));
    return directionality == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT ||
       directionality == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT_ARABIC;
}

private void populateButtons(int i, Button word_btn) {
    word_btn[i] = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    word_btn[i].setText("");
    word_btn[i].setId(i);
    word_btn[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    word_btn[i].setTextSize(24);
    word_btn[i].setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    word_btn[i].setLayoutParams(param);
    word_btn[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.matchbox);
    world_layout.addView(word_btn[i]);
    word_btn[i].setOnClickListener(charOnClick(word_btn[i]));
}

private void createWord(int length) {
    LinearLayout world_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.world_layout);
    LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, length);

    word_btn = new Button[length];

    if(isRTL()) {
        for(int j = length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            populateButtons(j, word_btn);
        }
    } else {}
    for (int k = 0; k < length; k++) {
        populateButtons(k, word_btn)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days, I found the solution. It was easy as a piece of cake.
I dont know why I make it so compilacated.
I just change the my if clause like this:

```
    for (int i = length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        word_btn[i] = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        word_btn[i].setText("");
        word_btn[i].setId(i);
           word_btn[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        word_btn[i].setTextSize(24);
        word_btn[i].setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        word_btn[i].setLayoutParams(param);
    word_btn[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.matchbox);
        world_layout.addView(word_btn[i]);
    word_btn[i].setOnClickListener(charOnClick(word_btn[i]));
    }
```