# Localization in Android RTL design

Tags: android

I am working on localization in android.Can anyone suggest what is the best way to deal with RTL screens for Arabic language. i want design to set alignment if the user is selecting Arabic in languages

Comment: what research have you done already? I'm sure someone else on earth must have had the same question.

Comment: There are plenty of articles you can find on google. https://android.jlelse.eu/rtl-support-on-android-here-is-all-you-need-know-e13f2df512e2

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996183/identifying-rtl-language-in-android

Answer (score 1):

OK   to support RTL and be Like LTR without error in design

1- when You Use Margin and Padding and Gravity  Use Start Or End .. not Using Right Or Left

```
android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
```

Not

```
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
```

2- store All String In **String.Xml**

```
                android:hint="@string/weight"
```

Not

```
                android:hint="weight"
```

3- it`s Prefer to use **minSdkVersion**   to be **17**

4 - if you have Image What Direction Change "Like Back Button "
Use Vector Image With Monitor RTL

[image]

Comment: ok i got u....can we make different layout for RTL then we use call that layout instead

Comment: Yes you can ,, But Do it Only your design Will Completely different

and I don`t Advice you with this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <application
        android:supportsRtl="true">
// YOUR ACTIVITY

</application>
```